# Are District Mayors Elected?

Tags: the-hunger-games

In the Districts do the citizens elect their Mayor or is he/she appointed by the Capitol?

Comment: I believe it’s strongly implied that the Mayor is appointed by the Capitol, but I don’t have a reference to hand.

Answer (score 3):

**Book canon** - as far as I'm aware, no elections are ever mentioned (just read and text-searched the books; and checked the Wiki). Based on everything else we know of the society (and Capitol's control), it's unlikely that they would permit Mayors to be elected instead of appointed.

The only time "elections" are mentioned is in this context:

> President Snow goes on to tell us what happened in the previous Quarter Quells. “On the twenty-fifth anniversary, as a reminder to the rebels that their children were dying because of their choice to initiate violence, every district was made to hold an election and vote on the tributes who would represent it.”

The only other mentions of elections are non-Mayor-related stuff in "Mockingjay" that I won't quote as it's spoiler-y. There is also no mention of "appointments", though.

---

**Film semi-canon**: viral promotional campaign had "elections for mayor": http://www.movieviral.com/2011/12/07/the-hunger-games-viral-campaign-for-mayor-of-your-district/ and http://www.myhungergames.com/the-capitol-begins-district-mayoral-elections. I'm somewhat unsure of how canonical that is.

[image]